# How to deskew a scanned text page with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I have scanned documents that weren't scanned perfectly straight so the text is not orientated perfectly horizontally, i.e. perhaps 10° of a slope on each line.

My understanding is that the deskew option in ImageMagick should solve this, for example

```
convert skewed_1500.jpeg -deskew 40% skewed_1500_not.jpg
```

but it doesn't have any noticeable effect on the output file.

I've attached the skewed and deskewed images for comparison.

First the original image:
[image: skewed image]

Then the purportedly deskewed image:
[image: deskewed image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would try a bigger value like 80% otherwise an Imagemagick forum member has a bash script that may be better: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textdeskew/index.php

Comment: Excellent, your 80% suggestion did the job perfectly. I also tried the script that you linked to and the bare script, without playing with parameters, did deskew somewhat but nt as perfectly as your 80% suggestion. Many thanks, this one has gone into the toolbox.

Comment: What exactly does the percentage mean? I can understand an angle, but a percentage makes no sense to me. Also, no matter how high I set the value, convert doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: I tested with a form flipped 90 degrees clockwise and the textdeskew script was not able to perform the proper orientation. The page was flipped down, as the documentation warns.

Answer (score 4):

## with [OCRmyPDF](https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF)

You can also straighten the pages after first having ImageMagick convert your JPG to PDF (`convert input.jpg input.pdf`) and then letting OCRmyPDF rectify the PDF:

```
ocrmypdf --deskew --tesseract-timeout=0 input.pdf output.pdf
```

Using your example page, I'd say the resulting text is straight:

[image: straightened page, after running OCRmyPDF]

As documented [here](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#don-t-actually-ocr-my-pdf), `--tesseract-timeout=0` disables optical character recognition.

Of course you can also deskew the PDF and make it searchable in one go:

```
ocrmypdf --deskew -l fra input.pdf output.pdf
```

Make sure to have the French language pack from Tesseract installed before running this. [Here](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/languages.html) are instructions.

### Crop the PDF

To get rid of the black parts on the sides and the white part on the bottom of the PDF, you can use [`pdfcrop`](https://github.com/ho-tex/pdfcrop) (commonly part of [TeX Live](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TeX_Live)):

```
# Remove margins at left, top, right, and bottom
pdfcrop --margins '-60 0 -50 -430' output.pdf cropped_output.pdf
```

The cropped and deskewed PDF:

[image: PDF cropped with pdfcrop]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use Imagemagick but it does the same job of deskew-ing the scanned document/image.

Following is the piece of code that can help you deskew the image:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import rotate
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from deskew import determine_skew
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def deskew(_img):
    image = io.imread(_img)
    grayscale = rgb2gray(image)
    angle = determine_skew(grayscale)
    rotated = rotate(image, angle, resize=True) * 255
    return rotated.astype(np.uint8)

def display_before_after(_original):
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(io.imread(_original))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(deskew(_original))

display_before_after('img_35h.jpg')
```

Reference and Source: http://aishelf.org/deskew/

Answer (score 0):

You have the right syntax in Imagemagick, but just increase the percentage to 60%.

Input:

[image]

```
convert skewed_1500.jpeg -deskew 60% x.jpg
```

[image]