Deskew image using opencv in Python
I am preprocessing images of PDFs which will eventually have text extracted from them. I am using opencv for the bulk of the preprocessing work and due to constraints of the client environment, I can really only stick to using opencv for the image processing. I have a function (below) to deskew my image so that it is in the correct orientation and the text can be extracted further down the line (using pytesseract). Before the function is run, I convert the PDF into an image and resize it into a predetermined size (approximately the same size as the original). Both of these functions work perfectly fine and do not appear to be the culprit in my issues below.
Of all these images, there's an approx. 50-50 split between images that are perfectly oriented with text nice and straight in the image and then others that are slightly cooked enough to be visibly off and also cause issues when attempting to extract the text. Thus, the need for a deskew function. I reviewed this article and leveraged the code in the article to create the below:
# Code courtesy of Leo Ertuna for Becoming Human: Artificial Intelligence Magazine 
## https://becominghuman.ai/how-to-automatically-deskew-straighten-a-text-image-using-opencv-a0c30aed83df

# Calculate skew angle of an image
def getSkewAngle(cvImage) -> float:
    # Prep image, copy, convert to gray scale, blur, and threshold
    newImage = cvImage.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(newImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9, 9), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # Apply dilate to merge text into meaningful lines/paragraphs.
    # Use larger kernel on X axis to merge characters into single line, cancelling out any spaces.
    # But use smaller kernel on Y axis to separate between different blocks of text
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (30, 5))
    dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=5)

    # Find all contours
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)

    # Find largest contour and surround in min area box
    largestContour = contours[0]
    minAreaRect = cv2.minAreaRect(largestContour)

    # Determine the angle. Convert it to the value that was originally used to obtain skewed image
    angle = minAreaRect[-1]
    if angle < -45:
        angle = 90 + angle
    return -1.0 * angle

def rotateImage(cvImage, angle: float):
    newImage = cvImage.copy()
    (h, w) = newImage.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
    newImage = cv2.warpAffine(newImage, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    return newImage

# Deskew image
def deskew(cvImage):
    angle = getSkewAngle(cvImage)
    if abs(angle) < 0.90:
        return rotateImage(cvImage, -1.0 * angle)
    else:
        return cvImage

I plugged in two images, one which is mostly at the proper angle and the other which is very clearly skewed.
print(getSkewAngle(working_pdf))
working_pdf_ds = deskew(working_pdf)
getSkewAngle(working_pdf_ds)

The output for the perfectly oriented image of the above is
-0.061542168259620667
-90.0

and the output for the crooked image is
-89.61195373535156
-90.0

Based on this new angle, I'd expect the image is now straightened and looks like the perfectly oriented image. However, when I look at the images themselves after being deskewed, the clearly skewed image is now rotated at a 270 degree angle (clockwise). I tried attempting to re-run the function on the skewed image to re-orient it, but when it was deskewed it cropped off the top and bottom of the image.
I'm not sure exactly where I've gone wrong with this or how to even begin to fix this, so would greatly appreciate any advice that can be shared.
The actual PDFs/images I am using contain PII, but I was able to replicate the issue with a sample image from the article from where I got the code and ran into the same issues.
Original

After running the deskew function

When printing the original angle of this sample image and then the angle after deskewing, I got the following output:
-90.0
-0.0

ETA: ended up creating a function that tries both the original code I've been using and the code on pyimagesearch suggested in the comments then uses tesseract to read some text in the image to determine which produces the "best" skew.

Perhaps see https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/

Perhaps also see nathancy's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660933/how-to-de-skew-a-text-image-and-retrieve-the-new-bounding-box-of-that-image-pyth

@fmw42 the pyimagesearch code works great on my skewed image, but then it messes up my working image and does the same thing (90 angle clockwise this time and cuts off the top)

@fmw42 nathancy's answer looked promising but when I looked it said the skew angle was 0 and thus didn't do anything to correct the skew.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63164341/improving-image-deskew-using-python-and-opencv

The Imagemagick -deskew works perfectly on your image above. It uses the Radon transform.  (One of the answers above uses Numpy to deskew.  See that). If you can use Python Wand, that uses Imagemagick, then desks method might solve your issue.  See the last link posted above.

why all of this? is the source pdf a scan, or is it exported from latex or msword or similar "authoring" programs? if it's not actually raster data, then all the text already exists in the PDF. please present authentic source data. generate it, if it's a matter of security/secrecy, but make sure it actually represents the problem.

you are likely mixing up radians and degrees. -- if you aren't familiar with transformation matrices, get familiar with them. rotation and translation are the basic operations you need. you need to understand what point you're rotating around, and how large the destination image needs to be.

all: check user's previous questions for more context. several revolve around rectifying pictures of documents.

The image is really good for "classically" deskewing it.
import cv2
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = cv2.imread("skewed.png") # read image
imGray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # turn to gray
imOTSU = cv2.threshold(imGray, 0, 1, cv2.THRESH_OTSU+cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1] # get threshold with positive pixels as text
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(imOTSU > 0)) # get coordinates of positive pixels (text)
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1] # get a minAreaRect angle
if angle < -45: # adjust angle
    angle = -(90 + angle)
else:
    angle = -angle
# get width and center for RotationMatrix2D
(h, w) = imGray.shape # get width and height of image
center = (w // 2, h // 2) # get the center of the image
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0) # define the matrix
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(im, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE) # apply it

After turning the text pixels into the positive class, get those as a column_stack and then use cv2.minAreaRect. After this, just adjust the angle as you are doing and apply a rotation matrix using cv2.warpAffine.
Here is also a small plot as to how this is working:

