# how to autocrop a deskewed scanned image

Tags: imagemagick, crop

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546181/how-to-deskew-a-scanned-text-page-with-imagemagick) approach, deskewing works great, how do I autocrop so it the outer border comes in until it finds a mostly white contiguous rectangle, so it could be auto-cropped after deskewing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Imagemagick  7, you can do an extreme trim using the new -define trim:percent-background=0% to remove all the background from the image. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim

Input:

[image]

```
magick skewed_1500.jpeg -background black -deskew 60% -background black -define trim:percent-background=0% -fuzz 1% -trim +repage x.jpg
```

Result:

[image]

**ADDITION:**

You can trim even more by trimming before the deskew. I had to use a large fuzz value to remove the bottom white. There must be some slight gray spot somewhere down there that I cannot see. But if there is no black border to start, you may trim too much white all around. That is the downside.

```
magick skewed_1500.jpeg -bordercolor white -border 1 -fuzz 75% -trim +repage -background black -deskew 60% -background black -define trim:percent-background=0% -fuzz 1% -trim +repage x.jpg
```

Result:

[image]