# Detect skewed image with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I previously [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365280/how-to-autocrop-a-deskewed-scanned-image/71365635#71365635) how to auto fix a skewed image, is there a way to simply detect that it is skewed with image magick?  I.e. is there a command that I could run on two images, one skewed and one not, and use that output as the determinant of whether it's skewed?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: Generally, no.  But if the image is text, then one can often use FFT processing to determine the rotation angle. For example I have a bash unix shell script that does that called textdeskew.  It find the rotation angle using FFT processing and then uses -rotate or -distort SRT to deskew.

Comment: would you please share the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction to my comment above. There is a way to determine the skew angle in Imagemagick if you have regular lines of text.

Input:

[image]

```
convert img.jpg -deskew 60% -format "%[deskew:angle]" info:

2.18111
```

See https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

Comment: @ fmw42 you've come through again, thank you so much

Comment: does this also work when it is potentially a trapezoidal prism skew, such as a camera photo taking a picture of a paper (instead of flatbed)

Comment: It will not correct for perspective distortion. It only works for rotation and possibly skew.